# flutter widget or layout need add const?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

For example, I have a Text Widget. When I insert (Alt+Insert) Padding, the value of the padding property is `const EdgeInsets.all(8.0)`. I don't quite understand why `const` is added. If all Widgets are added with Widget, there will be performance. Upgrade?  Is it like `const Text('text')`

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Text('text'),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`const` has a meaning that's a bit more complex and subtle in Dart. `const modifies` *values*. You can use it when creating collections, like const [1, 2, 3], and when constructing objects (instead of new) like const Point(2, 3).

[Here](https://news.dartlang.org/2012/06/const-static-final-oh-my.html) is the complete definition of `const`

Comment: I am confused, if adding const in every place of flutter will improve performance?

Comment: Not every place, but at that place where the value remains the same for the widget. if you put the const in front of the Text(), then that means the only single time memory space allocated and you never gonna change it.

Answer (score 1):

In Dart, their are basically 3 different specifier. `const`, `static` and `final`, each quite different from the other.

Now, the thing with `const` is that the compiler tries to calculate the value of that variable while at compile time. So, if you have something like : `const CONST_STRING = "String"`, then all the uses of `CONST_STRING` will be replaced by its value (ie "String"), by the compiler. This definitely provides a performance boost. But their is a point here. You cannot use `const` for everything, as it need to be accessible at the compile time.

So, you can definitely use primitive data types as `const`, but for objects, their constructor will have to support `const` (see the [EdgetInset](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/EdgeInsets-class.html) constructor).

Furthermore, to be able to make the constructor `const`, the class' member variables will have to be construct-able at compile time.

Comment: I am confused, if adding const in every place of flutter will improve performance?

Comment: `const` makes the value immutable, and if you are using something that's immutable, then can and probably should use `const`.

Answer (score 0):

Constructing two identical compile-time constants results in a single, canonical instance:

```
var a = const ImmutablePoint(1, 1);
var b = const ImmutablePoint(1, 1);

assert(identical(a, b)); // They are the same instance!
```

https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#using-constructors

In other words, your padding will be created only once this way, even if you use it 100 times (if you provided the same values for to constructor). I guess if you have many places with the same text it would make sense to make it a const too or to do it every time.

However I've yet to see a real performance analysis that indicates the performance gains of doing this. I'm not saying it's wrong, but you have to balance perf vs readability.